# What could be a better alternative to this For?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, for-loop

I'm a beginner trying to write up a game about trading in Python 3.x.

I have two classes (Depot and Good). Instances of the class Good are stored in a dictionary inside depot.inv (the instance as Key, and the amount of it as Value). When the user is asked to write what does he want to take, he will write the name of the instance ('Iron' instead of ir). So I took a For loop and searched through everything the Depot had in it's inventory. If he finds that the reply of the user is = to the name of any instance (ir.name, for example), then the program gains access to the instance as a whole.

The question is, how can I do this without a For-Loop?

I imagine that searching the whole inventory each time a reply is made is not optimal, even less if it's a linear search.

```
class Depot:
    def __init__ (self, name, inv, bank):
      self.name = name
      self.inv = inv
      self.bank = bank

class Good:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, rare):
      self.name = name
      self.weight = weight
      self.rare = rare

ir = Good('Iron', 1, 0.1)
gd = Good('Gold', 0.4, 2)
sl = Good('Silver', 0.7, 6.3)
mars = Depot('Mars', {ir: 10500, gd: 800, sl: 6000}, 1000)
player = {ir: 100}

reply = input('What do you want to take?')

i, q = reply.split()

for k in mars.inv.keys():    #This is the crux of the problem
  if i in k.name:
    x = k
    print('Got it')

if x in mars.inv:
  if int(q) > mars.inv[x]:
    print('We dont have that much.')
  elif int(q) <= mars.inv[x]:
    mars.inv[x] -= int(q)
    if x in player:
      player[x] += int(q)
    elif i not in player:
      player[x] = int(q)
```

Comment: This is the problem with storing something like a name, which may be the key of a lookup, internally within the object. It has some duplication, but changing your inventory to be something more like `{"Iron": (ir, 10500), "Gold": (gd, 800), "Silver": (sl, 6000}` would allow looking up by name directly. You could also make the `Good` class hashable/equatable on its name, so it acts as its name does during lookups, but that's a bit hacky.

Comment: You could also have multiple dictionaries. One dictionary maps name->object. Another maps name or object->quantity. Then you use whichever dictionary holds the relationship you're doing a lookup on. That's the standard trade-off between time/space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension and `next()` allows you to only find the first occurance of the item you're looking for, and then stop. Breaking the for loop after finding the key you're looking for would achieve the same thing. Both are O(n) there isn't really that much room to optimize. A one liner would be

`x = next((k for k in mars.inv.keys() if i in k.name), None)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably duplicate the name as the key of the dictionary and map it to a tuple of the other information:

```
{"Iron": (ir, 10500), "Gold": (gd, 800), "Silver": (sl, 6000}
```

Then you can do `mars.inv["Iron"]` to get the tuple of `(ir, 10500)`, and you can extract whichever data you want from that.

---

Note though, this requires an *exact* match on the name. You're currently using `in` to do the check, which will prevent any optimizations. Since from your description, you're doing lookups based on exact names (ignoring case, since that can be easily accounted for), `in` is unnecessary.